# Post xml request using retrofit2

Tags: android, xml, post, retrofit2

I have problem on post xml request using Retrofit. 
Below is my post xml request format:

```
    <GetRequest>
        <osType>02</osType>
    </GetRequest>
```

This is my Retrofit Service:

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"})
@POST("/mobileapi")
Call<Response> request(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

And this is how i call the object

```
String request = "<GetRequest>\n" + "    <osType>02</osType>\n" + "
</GetRequest>";
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/xml"),request);
final Call<Response> call = request.request(requestBody);
```

I have no idea how to solve the problem to avoid getting failure respond... need someone to assist me to fixed this problem.